# Mediawiki. Template-based/Static queries

Tags: mediawiki

I want to create a matrix of articles with some tag, or category, or something like that

```
|       | Page1   | Page2   | Page3   |  
| Page1 | Page_11 | Page_12 | Page_13 |
| Page2 | Page_21 | Page_22 | Page_23 |
| Page3 | Page_31 | Page_32 | Page_33 |
```

with clickable articles
I think that it is possible to make it in wikitext without using `js` or any other frontend thing and generate that code on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Use a  [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Table) with wikilinks.

```
{| class="wikitable"
! 
! Page A
! Page B
! Page C
|-
! Page 1
| [[Page 11]] || [[Page 12]] || [[Page 13]]
|-
! Page 2
| [[Page 21]] || [[Page 22]] || [[Page 23]]
|-
! Page 3
| [[Page 31]] || [[Page 32]] || [[Page 33]]
|}
```

Comment: It is manual approach. Is there an automatic way to build that table?

Comment: Not without [Extension:Semantic MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Semantic_MediaWiki)

Comment: I mean that you need to "hardcode" that table by hand. I expected there was a way to generate it using loops and conditionals